# Can we See the lwc Module?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

[This page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_javascript) in the LWC developer guide talks about a component JS file, in particular:

> Every UI component must include a JavaScript file with at least this code.
>
> ```
> import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
>     export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
> }
> ```
>
> The core module in Lightning Web Components is lwc. The import statement imports LightningElement from the lwc module.
>
> ```
> import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
> ```
>
> LightningElement is a custom wrapper of the standard HTML element.

Presently I'm learning about JS modules and importing/exporting them.  I understand that they are individual JS files.

So is there a way to see the lwc module referenced in the documentation?  If possible, what is in it and what does it look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit (2019-05-30): LWC is now open source! https://github.com/salesforce/lwc

Our intent is to open source LWC by the end of the year but it will ultimately come down to resourcing constraints because there's still a lot of work to do!

There's not too much going on in the `lwc` module. There's basically `LightningElement` which exposes an API subset of `HTMLElement` (what we consider the "good parts"). There are also the various decorators (`api`, `track`, `readonly`, `wire`) and several other APIs that are only usable by our compiler.

To answer your question though, a single file would be the simplest type of module, but a module can contain multiple files since we are able to import and export in the same file. You can event do that with a single line using [module redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Module_Redirects).

Comment: Would be great if it was developed in the open like salesforce lightning design system on github.  The distribution is public on npm.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to see the lwc module referenced in the documentation?

Not that I know of.

Unlike Lightning Aura Components, which was built on top of [Open Source Aura Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_open_source.htm), Lightning Web Components model at least as of today is not Open Sourced. This is more of a platform implementation for Web Standards and that unless Salesforce opens it up, there's no way of accessing any base code implemented in the LWC model.